# dynamic template based on login role using templaterProvider in AngularJS UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to render different templates based on the role of the logged in user. I am using templateProvider to achieve this in UI-Router but it doesnt seem to work. Made a quick example of what I am trying to achieve here : [http://plnkr.co/edit/J8Ebv4CQWHOjOpNoCkxl?p=preview]

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('test',['test.app','test.session','ui.router']);
angular.module('test.session',[])
.service('Session',['$http',function($http){
  this.current = function(){
    // this will be a custom server response later
    return $http.get('user.json');
  };
}]);
angular.module('test.app',['ui.router','test.session'])
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.
    $state('home',{
      url: '/',
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      templateProvider: ['Session','$stateParams','$templateFactory',function(Session,$stateParams,$templateFactory){
        return Session.current().then(function(user){
          // return template based on login role.
          console.log(user);
          if (user.isAdmin){
            return $templateFactory.fromUrl('admin.tpl.html',$stateParams);
          }else{
            return $templateFactory.fromUrl('user.tpl.html',$stateParams);
          }
        })
      }]
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
}])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  // Controller logic
}]);
```

I am stuck here dont know what I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNq8loLzdemlsgdevR9U?p=preview). 
The defintion should be like this:

```
// instead of this
$stateProvider.
    $state('home',{
// we need this
$stateProvider. 
    state('home',{
```

And also, the response is not the user:

```
Session.current()
  // instead of this
  .then(function(user){
  // we need this
  .then(function(response){
       var user = response.data;
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNq8loLzdemlsgdevR9U?p=preview)